# p:dataTable context menu "selection" object not updating

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am trying to update the selected row (object) in `<p:dataTable>` when user clicks on the context menu but the object bound to `<p:dataTable>` `selection=""` doesn't updates according to row selection/context menu click, the debugging showed that the object's attributes in the bean doesn't contain any updated values but empty.

The code is:

```
<h:form id="searchStdentsFrm">

    <p:dialog id="searchStdentsDlg" header="Search Students" widgetVar="srchStdents" modal="true">

        <p:contextMenu for="srchStdentsTble" id="menuStdEdit">
            <p:menuitem value="Change Status" update="stdDetail" icon="ui-icon-flag" oncomplete="PF('editStudentDialog').show()" />
            <p:menuitem value="Edit Student" update="stdStatusDetail" icon="ui-icon-wrench" oncomplete="PF('editStudentStatusDialog').show()" action="#{viewStudentsBean.testAction}"/>
        </p:contextMenu>

        <p:dataTable id="srchStdentsTble" var="student" value="#{viewStudentsBean.studentsList}"
                     rowKey="#{student.id}" selection="#{viewStudentsBean.selectedStudent}"
                     selectionMode="single" widgetVar="srchStdentTbl"
                     emptyMessage="No students found with the given criteria" filteredValue="#{viewStudentsBean.filteredStudents}">

            <p:ajax event="contextMenu"/>

            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputPanel>
                    <h:outputText value="Search Students:" />
                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('srchStdentTbl').filter()" style="width:200px" placeholder="Enter keyword"/>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>

            <p:column id="stdentId" headerText="Id" filterBy="#{student.id}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.id}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentFirstName" headerText="Firstname" filterBy="#{student.firstName}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.firstName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentLastname" headerText="Lastname" filterBy="#{student.lastName}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.lastName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentFathername" headerText="Father name" filterBy="#{student.fatherName}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.fatherName}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentGender" headerText="Gender" filterBy="#{student.gender}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.gender}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentDOB" headerText="Date Of birth" filterBy="#{student.dob}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.dob}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentSkype" headerText="Skype/Email" filterBy="#{student.skypeOrEmailId}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.skypeOrEmailId}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentPhone" headerText="Phone No" filterBy="#{student.phoneNumber}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.phoneNumber}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentAddrs" headerText="Address" filterBy="#{student.address}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.address}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentCountry" headerText="Country" filterBy="#{student.country}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.country}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentJOD" headerText="Joining Date" filterBy="#{student.dateOfJoining}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.dateOfJoining}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="stdentGenralRmrks" headerText="General Remarks" filterBy="#{student.generalRemarks}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.generalRemarks}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column id="studentStatus" headerText="Student Status" filterBy="#{student.studentStatus}" filterStyle="display:none">
                <h:outputText value="#{student.studentStatus}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

    </p:dialog>

    <p:dialog id="editStdentDlg" header="Edit Student" widgetVar="editStudentDialog" modal="true">
        <p:outputPanel id="stdDetail" style="text-align:center;">

            <p:outputLabel value="First Name *" />
            <p:inputText value="#{viewStudentsBean.selectedStudent.lastName}"/>

            <p:panelGrid id="editStdPanelGrd" columns="2" cellpadding="5" style="width: 100%;">
                <p:outputLabel value="First Name *" />
                <p:inputText id="stdEditFname" value="#{viewStudentsBean.selectedStudent.firstName}"/>

                <p:outputLabel value="Last Name *" />
                <p:inputText id="stdEditLastname" value="#{viewStudentsBean.selectedStudent.lastName}"/>

                <p:outputLabel value="Father's Name *" />
                <p:inputText id="stdEditFathName" value="#{viewStudentsBean.selectedStudent.fatherName}"/>

                <p:outputLabel value="Gender *" />
                <h:selectOneMenu id="stdEditGnder" value="#{viewStudentsBean.selectedStudent.gender}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Male" itemLabel="Male" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Female" itemLabel="Female" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>

                <p:outputLabel value="Date Of Birth *" />
                <p:calendar id="stdEditDOB" value="#{viewStudentsBean.selectedStudent.dob}"/>

                <p:outputLabel value="Skype Id/Email *" />
                <p:inputText id="stdEditSkype" value="#{viewStudentsBean.selectedStudent.skypeOrEmailId}"/>

                <p:outputLabel value="Phone No *" />
                <p:inputText id="stdEditPNo" value="#{viewStudentsBean.selectedStudent.phoneNumber}"/>

                <p:outputLabel value="Address *" />
                <p:inputText id="stdEditAddrs" value="#{viewStudentsBean.selectedStudent.address}"/>

                <p:outputLabel value="Country *" />
                <p:inputText id="stdEditCountry" value="#{viewStudentsBean.selectedStudent.country}"/>

                <p:outputLabel value="Date of joining *" />
                <p:calendar id="stdEditDOJ" value="#{viewStudentsBean.selectedStudent.dateOfJoining}"/>

                <p:outputLabel value="General Remarks" />
                <p:inputText id="stdEditGR" value="#{viewStudentsBean.selectedStudent.generalRemarks}"/>
            </p:panelGrid>

        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>

    <p:dialog id="editStdentStatusDlg" header="Edit Student" widgetVar="editStudentStatusDialog" modal="true">
        <p:outputPanel id="stdStatusDetail" style="text-align:center;">
            The current status of:<p:outputLabel value="#{viewStudentsBean.selectedStudent.lastName}"/>
            is: <p:outputLabel value="#{viewStudentsBean.selectedStudent.studentStatus}" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

PS: I am using JSF 2.2 with PrimeFaces 5.0

I am absolutely stuck here. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Actually the second dialog in which i wanted to display/edit the selection object binded to p:datatable, required to be updated in context menu like:

```
update=":searchStdentsForm:editStdentDlg"
```

means the form and dialog needed to be explicitly referred.